# Arithmetic Operations -Java

Tags: java, math, addition, operations

```
 class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(12+8/5%4*(5-4/5)+4*5);
    }
 }
```

Why the output is 37? Can anyone explain? I'm a beginner in java

Comment: Ditto Eran. We can't really explain your misconception and help you understand why it is what it is, unless we know what you expect and why.

Comment: I don't get 37 in my calculations .i got 12+8 together and 5%4 together .What's the fault in it?

Comment: Operator precedence? Is 2*3+5 =5+2*3? Is 5+3*2=5+2*3?

Comment: Those are elementary maths. You may not even need to know Java to know how to calcuate the result

Comment: Nelumi, check my post, there I explain in detail every detail

Comment: Okay thank you Héctor Manuel Martinez Durán

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about maths, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [precedence of the operators](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) in java:

```
12+8/5%4*(5-4/5)+4*5
12+8/5%4*(5-0)+4*5
12+8/5%4*5+4*5
12+1%4*5+4*5
12+1*5+4*5
12+5+20
37
```

Answer (score 0):

You have: `12+8/5%4*(5-4/5)+4*5`

In the post of user3134614

```
12+8/5%4*(5-4/5)+4*5
12+8/5%4*(5-0)
12+8/5%4*5+4*5
12+1%4*5+4*5
12+1*5+4*5
12+5+20
37
```

You have the basic operators

- `+` add two numbers
- `-` subtract two numbers
- `*` Multiply two numbers
- `/` divide two numbers

And these, a little more advanced

- `%` gets the remainder of two numbers, that is, that divides them and obtains the remainder, if the number is even, then the rest is zero, and if it is odd, it is another number

  For example `4%4` would be `4` divided by `4` results in `2` and `2 + 2` = `4`, there is no remainder, on the other hand `5%4` = `1`, because `2 + 2` = `4` and over 1 of 5
- The parentheses `()` separate a mathematical expression and return it as a single quantity, example

  `5 - (3-2) * 2` is equivalent to `5 - (1) * 2` = `5 - 2` = `3`

Then

```
12+8/5%4*(5-4/5)+4*5
12+8/5%4*(5-0) is 12+8/5%4*(5 - (4/5) = 0.8, but converted to integer is 0, then 5 - 0 = 5)
12+8/5%4*5+4*5 is 12+ (8/5 = 1.6, but to integer is 1) %4*5+4*5
12+1%4*5+4*5 is 12+ (1%4 = 1 (1 is different of 4 then result is 1)) *5+4*5
12+1*5+4*5 is 12 + (1*5 = 5) + (4*5 = 20)
12+5+20 and 12 + 5 + 20 = 37
37
```